# How can I get nginx to allow error log overwrites?

Tags: nginx, error-logging

In my nginx setup, if I manually edit the error log, errors no longer log. I suspect this is the desired/default behavior, as error logs aren't meant to be edited.

As my site is in development, though, I would prefer to edit the error log to be able to more easily see errors. Or, possibly better solution, log to a second, editable error log. Any good solutions out there? Thank you!